# ath6kl: interface is not up for AP mode

Tags: android, wifi, tethering

I have AR6003 chip on my Android 4.2.2 device. I recently switched to open source ath6kl driver, but I am having issue getting access point running. Actually, I can, but in a weird way.

I am using:

- hostapd v2.0-devel-4.2.2
- wpa_supplicant v2.0-devel-4.2.2

This is how I run the hostapd service in init.rc:

```
   mkdir /data/misc/wifi/hostapd 0770 wifi wifi
   chmod 0660 /data/misc/wifi/hostapd.conf

service hostapd /system/bin/hostapd -dd /data/misc/wifi/hostapd.conf
    class main
    socket hostapd_wlan0 dgram 660 root wifi
    user root
    group wifi
    oneshot
    disabled
```

Hostapd.conf file:

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ctrl_interface=/data/misc/wifi/hostapd
ssid=AndroidAP
channel=6
ieee80211n=1
```

When I enable Wi-Fi tethering option in Android UI, the checkbox is checked, but the notification about an active tether is no appearing and AP mode is not working.
This is what Android reports: https://gist.github.com/TheWhisp/6176213

When the AP mode is in this "semi-working" state, via adb shell I manually start hostapd (with su permissions):

```
hostapd -dd /data/misc/wifi/hostapd.conf
```

and then the AP mode is working. When I disable it and re-enable it, it gives errors that wlan0 is already used and fails.

Any idea why it happens like this? Thanks ;)